# make picture cut instead of resize with the page

Tags: html, css

I have a picture on my site which i want to stay always on same resolution, i.e, when i resize the page i want the picture to 'close-up' towards the middle of it inside of the holder instead of growing with it.
i guess i only miss the correct css attribute and every help will be appritiated:

```
<ul class="slides">
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item;"><img width="2560" height="495" src="images/5.jpg"></li>
    <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item;"><img width="2560" height="495" src="images/4.jpg"></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item;"><img width="2560" height="495" src="images/3.jpg"></li>

</ul>
```

the reason there is a -100% margin is because they are in a slider. i dont think its relevant to the problem i have.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clip property in CSS3 - [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)

Also check out [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) it is a jquery based image crop tool

Hope it helps

Comment: hello and thank you for your answer, unfortunatlly, the clip sets a rectangale of a specific size and i need a full screen.